# Is it safe to drink my contaminated water?

Tags: die2nite

A zombie fell into my town's well and couldn't get out. It died in there. I feel sorry for the thing but there really wasn't much we could do.

Anyways, apparently our town water's contaminated now, meaning that, in the game's words, "drinking it [today] would be a great way to get infected". Does this mean that if I drink the water I'll be guaranteed to get an infection, or is it based on chance?

Also, we've got some water rations from today in the bank. If I take one of them out tomorrow, will it still be infected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gazette is a lie(Guess it's more of a joke, than a lie). The water is safe to drink!

Comment: it might be unimlemented at the time. or something they dropped as a functionality. i wish i could read the developers minds.

Comment: As far as I know mordi is correct here, its just the game messing with new players for a bit of fun but intentionally does not infect any of your water.